# How can I show subcategories in categories?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5

**Here's the code**:

```
 public function getSubCategory(Request $request)

{

    $response = array();
    try {
        $categories = Category::where(['status' => 0, 'parent_id' => 0])- >get();
        $subCategory = Category::where('status', 0)->where('parent_id', '!=', 0)->get();

        foreach ($subCategory as $sub) {

            $categoryTitle = Category::where(['id' => $sub->parent_id])- >get(['title']);


            $result[] = array(

                'cat_title' => $categoryTitle[0]->title,
                'sub_title' => $sub->title,

            );
        }
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                $response = (new ApiMessageController())->successResponse($result, "Categories List Found!");
            } else {
                $response = (new ApiMessageController())->failedresponse("No Categories List Found");
            }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $response = (new ApiMessageController())->queryexception($ex);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

I will like to display parent category and its children under it. Something like this:

> 1. Category
>
>    - Sub 1
>    - Sub 2
> 2. Category
>    - Sub 1
>    - Sub 2

I want to show data like [see demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc6or.png)

Database Structure.
Both categories and subcategories are in same table.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtJTY.png)

Comment: First, can you show us how your database is designed ? I mean do you have a category and a subcategory table ? or both are the same table but differencied by an attribute ?

Comment: You should use nested tree 
For example
https://github.com/atayahmet/laravel-nestable
https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: Is that your database has nth level parent-child relation ? or only two level like parent and child relation?

Comment: @TrickStar two level parent and child relation. I have attached database with code.

Comment: @SteveNosse both are in same table.  I have attached database with code.

Comment: @DaniyalMughal sorry did'nt see it.
Let me write a piece of code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getSubCategory(Request $request)
{
    $response = array();
    try {
        $allData = array();
        // get all parent category 
        $categories = Category::where(['status' => 0, 'parent_id' => 0])->get();        
        foreach ($categories as $key=>$sub) {
            // now take one by one it's child category 
            $subCategory = Category::where('status', 0)->where('parent_id', '=', $sub->id)->get();
            $subCat = array();
            // set parent category title
            $allData[$key]['parent'] = $sub->title;
            foreach ($subCategory as $k=>$subcat) {
                $subCat[$subcat->id] = $subcat->title
            }
            // set child category array
            $allData[$key]['child'] = $subCat;
        }

        if (count($allData) > 0) {
            $response = (new ApiMessageController())->successResponse($allData, "Categories List Found!");
        } else {
            $response = (new ApiMessageController())->failedresponse("No Categories List Found");
        }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $response = (new ApiMessageController())->queryexception($ex);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'parent' => 'parent 1',
        'child'  => array(
                        '1' => 'child 1',
                        '2' => 'child 2'
                    )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'parent' => 'parent 2',
        'child'  => array(
                        '1' => 'child 1',
                        '2' => 'child 2'
                    )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u to use `NestedSet`. So you can create a category tree and get all data by depth.

But before you use it, you need to know

- Very comfortable to work with tree structure. (+)
- No recursive select(+)
- You may have a separate, normalized table (+)
- There may be a long request (-)

You can see all the deatils [here](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will proceed:

- First I will get all the categories
- Then I will get all the subcategories attached to each of the categories
- I will add this in a table
- Finally I will return the table.

This is how my code looks:

```
public function getSubCategory(Request $request){

    $response = array();
    try {
        $categories = Category::where(['status' => 0, 'parent_id' => 0])- >get();
        foreach ($categories as $c) {
            $subcategories = Category::where("parent_id", $c->id)->get();
            $response[] = [$c, $subcategories];
        }

        if (count($response) > 0) {
            $response = (new ApiMessageController())->successResponse($result, "Categories List Found!");
        } else {
            $response = (new ApiMessageController())->failedresponse("No Categories List Found");
        }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $response = (new ApiMessageController())->queryexception($ex);
    }
    return $response;
}
```